# Date algorithm to obtain 4 mondays ahead, changing on friday

Tags: algorithm, date

We're trying to obtain a date in the future so that it follows these rules:

- the date must be Monday
- the date must change every two weeks
- the date must be 4 weeks ahead (so that it's always in the future and doesn't come too close with the current date)
- the date must change on Friday at 3 pm

So, for example:

```
| on                                             | date is    |
|------------------------------------------------|------------|
| 2017-06-15                                     | 2017-07-04 |
| 2017-06-16 14:00:00 (friday before 15:00)      | 2017-07-04 |
| 2017-06-16 15:00:00 (friday after 15:00)       | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-16 16:00:00                            | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-18                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-19                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-20                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-21                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-22                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-23 (friday again, dates do not change) | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-24                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-25                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-26                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-27                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-28                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-29                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-30 14:00:00 (friday before 15:00)      | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-30 15:00:00 (friday after 15:00)       | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-06-30 16:00:00                            | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-01                                     | 2017-07-31 |
```

This is what I've come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/2yunw713/

It's a little bit rough and I started changing too much, so currently it's not even correct on the hour scale.

The algorithm can be in any language, I picked JavaScript just because it's so easy to test.

Comment: can you use https://momentjs.com/ ?

Comment: "In any language" - what do you intend to integrate this with?

Comment: The result for `2017-06-15` shouldn't be `2017-07-03`? Because `2017-07-04` is a Tuesday

Comment: "In any language" = "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this algorithm with Java 8's [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), although it's also possible to use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) for Java <= 7.

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

---

First of all, it's not clear how you set the initial Friday (when this all starts). So, I'm considering `2017-06-16 15:00` as the first Friday (where my algorithm starts; the last day when the change occured).

The algorithm is basically:

- get the last change date (some Friday at 15:00) and calculate when the next change will occur (2 weeks later)
- check if today's date is before the next change (if it's equals or after it, recalculate the change dates)
- get the next Monday 4 weeks ahead the last change

```java
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

// starting at 2017-06-16 15:00:00 (the last date when a change occured)
LocalDateTime lastChange = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 16, 15, 0);

// nextChange: 2 weeks after the last change
LocalDateTime nextChange = lastChange.plusWeeks(2);

// get the current date
LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();

// check if today is after or equals the nextChange
if (!today.isBefore(nextChange)) {
    // today is equal or after the next change, adjust the last and next change dates
    lastChange = nextChange;
    nextChange = lastChange.plusWeeks(2);
}

LocalDate futureDate = futureDate(lastChange);
System.out.println(futureDate);

// auxiliary method: get the future date based on the last change date
// using LocalDate because time (hour/minute/second) doesn't seem to matter in output
// (but if it does, use a LocalDateTime instead - don't call toLocalDate() in the last line)
public LocalDate futureDate(LocalDateTime lastChange) {
    // double checking (last change date is a Friday at 15:00) - not sure if it's really needed
    if (lastChange.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.FRIDAY || (!lastChange.toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.of(15, 0)))) {
        return null; // if the change it's not Friday or it's not 15:00, it should return null? (not sure)
    }

    // get the next Monday and add 4 weeks
    return lastChange.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
                     .plusWeeks(4).toLocalDate();
}
```

The output (considering that today is `2017-06-19`) will be:

> 2017-07-17

I've also tested with `2017-06-30` at 14:00 (returns `2017-07-17`) and at 15:00 (returns `2017-07-31`). Testing with your examples also gave me the same results.

---

**Notes:**

- In your output examples, you're printing just year/month/day, so I used `LocalDate` class. If you also want the time fields (hour/minute/seconds), change the method to return a `LocalDateTime` instead, and remove the call to `toLocalDate()` in the `return` statement.
- As it's not clear to me when it's the first Friday (when this all started?), I'm assuming it's `2017-06-16`.
- **In your sample output, the result for `2017-06-15` shouldn't be `2017-07-03`? Because `2017-07-04` is a Tuesday**.

---

If you want the same output, you can make a loop like below (using the same `futureDate()` method, and assuming that the result for `2017-06-15` is `2017-07-03` as stated above).

Note that I used a `java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster` to get the next date - because when it's a Friday, I must check if it's a change date and get the result for 14:00, 15:00 and 16:00, and then go to the next day (so sometimes I need to set the time to 14:00, or add 1 hour, or add 1 day - and I choose the respective adjuster for each situation).

I also used a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to change the output format (when it's Friday change and it has a custom format for hours):

```java
// starting 2 weeks before 2017-06-16 15:00:00 (the last date when a change occured)
LocalDateTime lastChange = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 16, 15, 0).minusWeeks(2);

// nextChange: 2 weeks after the last change
LocalDateTime nextChange = lastChange.plusWeeks(2);

// starting at 2017-06-15
LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 15, 0, 0);

LocalTime twoPM = LocalTime.of(14, 0);
LocalTime threePM = LocalTime.of(15, 0);
LocalTime fourPM = LocalTime.of(16, 0);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
TemporalAdjuster adjuster; // adjuster for the next date

// adjuster for next hour
TemporalAdjuster nextHour = t -> t.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
// adjuster for next day
TemporalAdjuster nextDay = t -> t.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

System.out.println("| on                                             | date is    |");
System.out.println("|------------------------------------------------|------------|");
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    String sep = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("| ");
    if (today.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY) {
        if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(lastChange.toLocalDate(), today.toLocalDate()) == 7) {
            sep = " (friday again, dates do not change)";
            adjuster = nextDay;
            sb.append(today.toLocalDate());
        } else {
            LocalTime time = today.toLocalTime();
            if (time.equals(twoPM)) {
                sep = " (friday before 15:00)    ";
                adjuster = nextHour;
                sb.append(formatter.format(today));
            } else if (time.equals(threePM)) {
                sep = " (friday after 15:00)      ";
                adjuster = nextHour;
                sb.append(formatter.format(today));
            } else if (time.equals(fourPM)) {
                sep = "                           ";
                adjuster = nextDay;
                sb.append(formatter.format(today));
            } else {
                sep = " (friday before 15:00)     ";
                adjuster = nextHour;
                today = today.with(twoPM);
                sb.append(formatter.format(today));
            }
        }
    } else {
        // get the next day at start of day
        sep = "                                    ";
        adjuster = t -> LocalDate.from(t).plusDays(1).atStartOfDay();
        sb.append(today.toLocalDate());
    }

    // check if today is after or equals the nextChange
    if (!today.isBefore(nextChange)) {
        // today is equal or after the next change, adjust the last and next change dates
        lastChange = nextChange;
        nextChange = lastChange.plusWeeks(2);
    }

    LocalDate futureDate = futureDate(lastChange);
    sb.append(sep).append(" | ").append(futureDate).append(" |");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    // get the next date
    today = today.with(adjuster);
}
```

The output is:

```java
| on                                             | date is    |
|------------------------------------------------|------------|
| 2017-06-15                                     | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 14:00:00 (friday before 15:00)      | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 15:00:00 (friday after 15:00)       | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-16 16:00:00                            | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-18                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-19                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-20                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-21                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-22                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-23 (friday again, dates do not change) | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-24                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-25                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-26                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-27                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-28                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-29                                     | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-30 14:00:00 (friday before 15:00)      | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-30 15:00:00 (friday after 15:00)       | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-06-30 16:00:00                            | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-01                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-02                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-03                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-04                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-05                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-06                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-07 (friday again, dates do not change) | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-08                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-09                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-10                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-11                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-12                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-13                                     | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-14 14:00:00 (friday before 15:00)      | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-07-14 15:00:00 (friday after 15:00)       | 2017-08-14 |
| 2017-07-14 16:00:00                            | 2017-08-14 |
| 2017-07-15                                     | 2017-08-14 |
| 2017-07-16                                     | 2017-08-14 |
| 2017-07-17                                     | 2017-08-14 |
| 2017-07-18                                     | 2017-08-14 |
```

---

Another alternative is to create a map to store all the future dates relative to the dates where the changes occur (so you don't need to calculate it all the time):

```java
// maps a change date with the respective future date
Map<LocalDateTime, LocalDate> futureDates = new HashMap<>();

// starting at 2017-06-16
LocalDateTime change = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 16, 15, 0);
// storing just 30 dates, but you can change this accordingly, with as many dates as you need
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    futureDates.put(change, futureDate(change));
    change = change.plusWeeks(2);
}
```

The check will change a little bit, as you need to know exactly what's the key corresponding to the date you're checking:

```java
LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();
// find the future date
for (LocalDateTime dt : futureDates.keySet()) {
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dt, today);
    if (days >= 0 && days <= 13) {
        System.out.println(today + "  " + futureDates.get(dt));
        break;
    }
}
```

This works the same way as the first version above.

Answer (score 1):

Any language... so here is bash solution =)

```sh
readonly start_date='2017-06-15'
# first monday after start_date
readonly start_mon="$(date -d "$start_date -$(date -d $start_date +%u) day + 8 day")"
monday_id=2 # offset in weeks from start_mon
monday_str=$(date -d "$start_mon $monday_id week" +'%Y-%m-%d')
fri_cnt=1 # 1 if date has to be changed on first friday, else 0
printf '|%-30s|%-10s|\n' 'on' 'date is'
for d in $(seq 0 56)  # 4 mondays ahead
do
    printf '|%-30s|%-10s|\n' "$(date -d "$start_date $d day" +'%Y-%m-%d')" "$monday_str"
    if [[ $(date -d "$start_date $d day" +'%a') == $(date -d 'fri' +'%a') ]]
    then  # it's friday
        fri_cnt=$((fri_cnt+1))
        if [[ $fri_cnt == 2 ]]
        then # it's second friday, change date
            fri_cnt=0
            monday_id=$((monday_id+2))
            monday_str=$(date -d "$start_mon $monday_id week" +'%Y-%m-%d')
            printf "|%-30s|%-10s|\n" "$(date -d "$start_date 15:00 $d day" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$monday_str"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
|on                            |date is   |
|2017-06-15                    |2017-07-03|
|2017-06-16                    |2017-07-03|
|2017-06-16 15:00:00           |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-17                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-18                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-19                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-20                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-21                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-22                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-23                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-24                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-25                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-26                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-27                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-28                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-29                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-30                    |2017-07-17|
|2017-06-30 15:00:00           |2017-07-31|
|2017-07-01                    |2017-07-31|
|2017-07-02                    |2017-07-31|
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put a Python solution which works as a library or a flexible command line script below.

Run as `./script.py demo`, it generates a chart similar to what you have (I've had to manually interleave the switch hours):

```
| on                                             | date is    |
|------------------------------------------------|------------|
| 2017-06-15 00:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 00:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-17 00:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-18 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-19 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-20 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-21 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-22 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-23 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-24 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-25 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-26 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-27 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-28 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-29 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-30 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-07-01 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-07-02 00:00                               | 2017-07-31 |
```

Run with, e.g. `./script.py 2017-06-15 2017-06-18 3`, it will generate a chart between the two dates with a 3 hour spacing between entries:

```
| on                                             | date is    |
|------------------------------------------------|------------|
| 2017-06-15 00:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 03:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 06:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 09:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 12:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 15:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 18:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-15 21:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 00:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 03:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 06:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 09:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 12:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 15:00                               | 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-06-16 18:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-16 21:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 03:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 06:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 09:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 12:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 15:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 18:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-17 21:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-18 00:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
| 2017-06-18 03:00                               | 2017-07-17 |
```

The script is as follows:

```or-tag-here
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import sys

MONDAY = 0 # 0 = Monday, 1=Tuesday, 2=Wednesday...
FRIDAY = 4

#Date of first change Friday. All future changes are calculated from here
FIRST_PREV_FRIDAY = datetime.datetime(2017,6,2,15,0,0)  

#Get the next weekday following the query_date
def GetNextWeekday(query_date, wdaynum):
  days_ahead = wdaynum - query_date.weekday()                      #0 = Monday, 1=Tuesday, 2=Wednesday, ...
  if days_ahead<=0:                                                #Day already happened this week
    days_ahead += 7                                                #Add 7 days to get the next day
  new_date = query_date + datetime.timedelta(days_ahead)           #Do date math to get the day in datetime
  return new_date

#Get a weekday several weeks in advance
def GetWeekdayInFuture(query_date, wdaynum, weeks_out):
  wd = query_date                                                  #Starting with the current day
  for i in range(weeks_out):                                       #Loop for a given number of weeks
    wd = GetNextWeekday(wd, wdaynum)                               #Calculating the next occurence of the day of interest
  return wd                                                        #Return the day

#Get a list of (current_date,next_monday) pairs between start_date and end_date
def GetMondays(start_date, end_date, date_increment):
  assert date_increment <= datetime.timedelta(days=1)              #If it were larger, we might skip changes!
  assert start_date     >= FIRST_PREV_FRIDAY                       #Can't calculate into the past

  #The idea is that we'll begin calculating from a point where we know things
  #are correct and only provide output in the user's specified region of
  #interest
  prev_friday   = FIRST_PREV_FRIDAY                                #First Friday at which a change took place
  change_friday = GetWeekdayInFuture(prev_friday, FRIDAY, 2)       #Next Friday at which a change will take place
  this_date     = prev_friday                                      #Set the current date to one for which we know the answer
  #Match hours minutes to start_date
  this_date     = this_date.replace(hour=start_date.hour, minute=start_date.minute)

  mondays = []                                                     #Holds the output list
  while this_date<=end_date:                                       #If current date is before the end date
    if this_date>=change_friday:                                   #Check if we've moved past a change point
      prev_friday   = change_friday                                #If so, this day becomes the point from which the future Monday is calculated
      change_friday = GetWeekdayInFuture(change_friday, FRIDAY, 2) #Calculate the next change point, two weeks in the future
    next_monday = GetWeekdayInFuture(prev_friday, MONDAY, 5)       #The Monday of interest is 5 weeks from the previous change point
    this_date += date_increment                                    #Advance to the next day
    if this_date>=start_date:                                      #Is this a date we were interested in?
      mondays.append((this_date,next_monday))                      #Gather output

  return mondays

#Get a particular Monday
def GetMondayForDate(query_date):
  start_date = FIRST_PREV_FRIDAY
  end_date   = query_date
  mondays    = GetMondays(start_date, end_date, datetime.timedelta(days=1))
  return mondays[-1][1]

#Print a nicely formatted charge of the Mondays
def PrintChart(mondays):
  print("| on                                             | date is    |")
  print("|------------------------------------------------|------------|")
  for x in mondays:
    print("| {0:47}| {1:11}|".format(x[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),x[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))

#Code to run if script were executed from the command line; otherwise, it works
#as a library
def main():
  if len(sys.argv)==1:
    print("Syntax:")
    print("\t{0:20}                                 - This help screen".format(sys.argv[0]))
    print("\t{0:20} demo                            - Demonstration chart".format(sys.argv[0]))
    print("\t{0:20} <START DATE> <END DATE> <Hours> - Chart between two dates with increment of hours".format(sys.argv[0]))
  elif sys.argv[1]=='demo':
    start_date = datetime.datetime(2017,6,15,0,0,0)        #Date from which to begin calculating
    end_date   = datetime.datetime(2017,7,1,0,0,0)         #Last date for which to calculate
    mondays    = GetMondays(start_date, end_date, datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    PrintChart(mondays)
  else:
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%Y-%m-%d")
    end_date   = datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[2], "%Y-%m-%d")
    hours      = int(sys.argv[3])
    mondays    = GetMondays(start_date, end_date, datetime.timedelta(hours=hours))
    PrintChart(mondays)

if __name__ == '__main__': #Was the script executed from the command line?
  main()
```

Gives this output chart (when I interleave data from `hours=1`):